# how to solve this exception :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, loops, methods, bin

i got this exception after i run my code i don't know what is the problem!!

the program initially creates int array then string array with the same length same as int,then take every index in v and convert it to binary and adds zeroes if the digits less than 4 then store it in the string index after manipulating the string array it passes it to method Called toBinaryInteger which return int array the toBinaryInteger method creates an array of length st.length*4 which supposed to be 32 then takes each entery from st and takes each digit of it and stores it in the p array then the program print the result but the exception is shown up at this moment of time . i hope i explain the program very well . any idea help please.

**hi every body problem solved**  the problem is i was printing the wrong array insted of result i printed st special tankx for the good debugger

```
 public static void main(String [] arg) 
    {   
        int [] v={0,11,12,13,14,15,7,8};
        String [] st=new String [v.length];
        String x="";
        for(int i=0;i<st.length;i++)
        {
            x=Integer.toBinaryString(v[i]);
            while (x.length()<4)    // add zeroed to left if needed to fit in 4 bits
                x="0"+x;
            st[i]=x;


        }
        int [] result=toBinaryInteger(st);
        int count=0;
        for(int k=0;k<result.length;k++)
        {
            System.out.print(st[k]);
            if(count==4){
                System.out.print("  ");
                count=0;
            }

        }



    }   






public static int [] toBinaryInteger(String [] s)
    { 
        int [] p=new int [s.length*4];
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
            {
            for(int j=0; j<s[i].length();j++){
                p[i*4+j]=Integer.parseInt(s[i].substring(j,j+1));//create array of 32 lenght    

                }
            }
            return p;   
    }
```

Comment: Is toBinaryInteger() actually returning an array of the same size?

Comment: **Where** does the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` occur? If you compile for debugging, the stack trace will tell you the specific line on which the error occurs. **That's step 1** in debugging this.

Comment: no who said that actualy it returns an array of length 32

Comment: @Lambert: No, it's returning an array four times the size, as you can tell from the code.

Comment: Do you have a line number in your stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

I compiled your code.  The resulting error told me that the problem appears to be this line:

```
System.out.print(st[k]);
```

Perhaps you meant to print `result[k]` there instead?

Comment: oh god, you are a good debugger seriously. i missed it thank you .like to your answer